# Pulling data and loop with php

Tags: php, xml, soap, foreach, pull

I have a php file that is trying to get information from a XML API using SOAP.

The code for pulling data is

```
 <?php
  // create SOAP client object
  $client = new SoapClient("http://www.bookingassist.ro/test/book.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));

  try {
      $rooms = array(); 
      // First Room
      $rooms[] = array(array("paxType" => "Adult"));
      $filters[] = array("filterType" => "resultLimit", "filterValue" => "6");     
      // (start search)
      $checkAvailability = $client->getAvailableHotel("APIKEY", "RHMK", "2015-04-20", "2015-04-27", "EUR", "RO", "false", $rooms, $filters);
  }
  catch (SoapFault $exception) {
      echo $exception->getMessage();
      exit;
  }

?>
 <?php
  if (is_object($checkAvailability->availableHotels)) 
  $hotelResponse[] = $checkAvailability->availableHotels;
  $hotelResponse = $checkAvailability->availableHotels;
  foreach ((array)$hotelResponse as $hnum => $hotel)
?>
```

below in page i have the folowing code

```
<article class="box">
<h4><?php echo  $hotel->hotelCode?></h4>                                      
<span class="price">aprox/NOAPTE</small>€ <?php echo $hotel->totalPrice ?></span>
</article>
```

My query is can i loop the entire content from   as many responses i have in the filters array (`$filters[] = array("filterType" => "resultLimit", "filterValue" => "6")`;  )

I have tried the same but in a blank page withour any css onky a table with header abd uts extracting and  looping the information as requested. - http://www.bookingassist.ro/test/test.php

Comment: Hi Razvan, welcome to SO. Please reduce the code you post to an absolute, but working minimum, so that it demonstrates what you are asking, but without the complexity. Moreover, please provide the XML itself, also as a working minimum. You will get precise answers then.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to minimise the code. Hope to find an answer as i am strugling with this for few days,

Comment: what does `var_dump($checkAvailability);` get you?

Comment: its pulling and shows 6 responses with all the variables availeble for $checkAvailability                                eg : object(stdClass)#2 (4) { ["responseId"]=> int(69560) ["searchId"]=> string(11) "XF-51806556" ["totalFound"]=> int(6) ["availableHotels"]=> array(6) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (9) { ["processId"]=> string(11) "H7-24700606" ["hotelCode"]=> string(6) "ITXN2I" ["availabilityStatus"]=> string(19) "InstantConfirmation" ["totalPrice"]=> float(2733) ["totalTax"]=> float(0) ["totalSalePrice"]=> float(0) ["currency"]=> string(3) "EUR etc

Comment: as far as I see, this has nothing to do with XML. Pls add this output to your question. rewrite your question. delete the xml tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only getting one result I don't think the values you have in "$hotelResponse" are what you think.

There's a good chance that your code is entering the second part of your if/else statement explaining why you are only getting one result.

Do a var_dump on this to verify you have X amount of hotels